# Refreshing a Power Query changes formula references and does not copy down table formulas

Tags: sql, excel, powerquery, excel-2016

I have several power queries, lets take a roster one as an example.

If I change a query parameter, such as a client name, and refresh it, and the query pulls more rows than it did before, the tables formulas will not be copied down to these new rows. It also causes cell references to shift.

Is there any way to refresh a power query, and have it pull in more/fewer rows and continue to copy down formulas in the same table?

Comment: This might require a new Excel feature. Want to submit an idea at https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/category/143418-data-import?